# Do Path Payments Work w/ Liquidity Pools?

Tags: path-payment

I'm pretty sure path payments use liquidity pools in their paths, but it seems it does not do so in the below transaction, where I'm swapping `USDC:GCWGBJURIDO4HKAF7EEHDDZO5VEAHGSCOMBR4SNJO3OQI5EQMP54RY7E` for `Soldiers:GAFA5RRXQV3COBA4OP7THTMXNBJUI5PM7A7HZKHLIWREZ7CHQIBV7SXF` from account `GBADYQMMWBSFWM2VJDBXS6KMJXCB3WWT6Y4ACR3IHEEA4ZA22RGH4GMB`.

You can use [Horizon](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#txsubmitter?network=test) to view the contents of the transaction

```
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
```

However, when I run in Horizon, I get

```
extras.result_codes:
{"transaction":"tx_failed","operations":["op_success","op_too_few_offers"]} 
Result XDR:
AAAAAAAAAMj/////AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC////9gAAAAA=
```

I don't think there are too few offers, I would expect the following path to be used

1. `USDC:GCWGBJURIDO4HKAF7EEHDDZO5VEAHGSCOMBR4SNJO3OQI5EQMP54RY7E` => `DOLLAR:GBMLAJ3MYHUL4FD245TGZWAMJ2D5ANJDKKDYRB5XKOU6D7AN7HE6O2QF` via [this SDEX order](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/offers?selling=DOLLAR%3AGBMLAJ3MYHUL4FD245TGZWAMJ2D5ANJDKKDYRB5XKOU6D7AN7HE6O2QF)
2. `DOLLAR:GBMLAJ3MYHUL4FD245TGZWAMJ2D5ANJDKKDYRB5XKOU6D7AN7HE6O2QF` => `Soldiers:GAFA5RRXQV3COBA4OP7THTMXNBJUI5PM7A7HZKHLIWREZ7CHQIBV7SXF` via [this liquidity pool](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/liquidity_pools/99e28edfba7bfa60be150b8a796df71b7b3ae44c921cb956e68fa78f1f266e51)

Why is the above path not being used?